# why model not fetching all attributes in table in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have created model for my databse and then run migration it successfully created the table in database after this I create migration to add column to that existing table . When I run **model.findall** query it only gets the attributes that I created first time e.g here is my model file

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = {
 up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
 return queryInterface.createTable('ActiveUsers', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  socketId: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
   });
 },
down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
return queryInterface.dropTable('ActiveUsers');
}
};
```

here is migration file to add column to this table

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
queryInterface.addColumn(
  'ActiveUsers',
  'Token',
  {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
   )

  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

 }
};
```

here is table pic
[image: table]
it only gets the attributes that are present in model file i.e

```
username,name,socketId,updatedAt,createdAt
```

why it dont get the value of

```
 token,status
```

here is my code

```
 activeusers.findAll({raw:true}).then(Users=>{

      console.log('online users')


    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The first file you wrote is not a model file, it is a migration file. If you want to select your new fields you should add them to your model file.

Your model file should look like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('activeUsers', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        name: {            
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        socketId: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        token: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        status: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
    });
};
```

You can read more in [Sequelize docs](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/articles/express/) about how to add models to your project.

Answer (score 0):

We have to add column fields to model file manually . then it will fetch that fields